# Sound problem while gaming on HP Pavilion DV4

Tags: sound, games, hp

I get a weird behavior with my volume every time I try to play a game with Desmume or even if I try to play Trine in Steam.

Volume goes up and down and it doesn't stop which makes gaming impossible.

Anyone has an idea to solve this?

I have an HP Pavilion DV4 2161nr.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried any steam game on Ubuntu yet. But for native games this works.

```
sudo rm /dev/input/js0
```

Comment: This needs to be explained better. How does removing a joystick device file help with sound problems?